# Speed up ranking query

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table hands where each entry represents a player's performance in a particular poker hand. The important columns are player and net. I wish to build a "highscores" page which showcases the best players based on total winnings with the ability to filter based on game type,time,etc. I've acheived this with the following query:

```
SELECT player,sum(net) AS profit FROM hands GROUP BY player ORDER BY profit DESC
```

Unfortunately I have many records, over 2 million to date, and this query is extremely slow. I've placed an index on "player" but execution time is still over 7 seconds. Is there any hope in speeding the mySQL up or do I have to go about constructing this page differently? If the latter, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to display all players? Try adding a LIMIT clause.

Comment: No but limit doesn't affect performance at all.

Comment: I would otherwise suggest a pre-aggregate table, but since you are considering qualifications based on types of games, time ranges, that would go out the window unless there was more constant criteria basis of queries.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to try this:

```
select p.*,
       (select sum(net) from hands h where h.player = p.player) as profit
from players p
order by profit desc;
```

Then, you need an index on `hands(player, net)`.  This might help by moving the aggregation into a subquery where it can make better use of an index.

If this doesn't work, you may be able reduce the set of players being considered -- for instance, only players who have played in the past week.  As a final alternative, you may need to change the structure of your tables.  In particular, consider adding a summary table that is kept up to date using triggers on the `hands` table.